# Html/Bootstrap : how to crop a video (reduction of its height)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use the following template : http://mamoot-themes.com/theme-preview/z-theme-1-2/home-video-bg.html

I would like to reduce the height of the video (cropping of the video in height ; preservation of the aspect ratio of the remaining visible area of the video)

How can I do?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just change the height of the `<video>` tag, it will preserve the aspect ratio without losing quality.